# OpenLayers: How to get *real* centroid of a Line Geometry/Feature?

Tags: openlayers-2, geometry, linestring, centroids

I have declared a line geometry as:

```
var lineString = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([source,target]);
```

then I am trying to get the centroid of this lineString as `lineString.getCentroid()`.

But what's returning is a Start Point of the lineString.

So, is there any way to get the *real* centroid of a LineString?

P.S: I have also looked through [this](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/centroid-for-linestrings-td3888765.html) discussion. But couldn't figure out the solution.

Comment: If I understand your link correctly all you have to do is to call `lineString.getCentroid(true)`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did the same exactly, but that didn't work. I mean it returns the same starting point. And apologies i didn't mention that here(while posting this question).

Comment: Try `lineString.getCentroid(weighted)`?

Comment: Hi, the HimBromBeere was right (Thanks!). So the solution is lineString.getCentroid(true). I believe earlier it was not worked because of browser cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [link](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/centroid-for-linestrings-td3888765.html) shared in question itself, the solution is to call `getCentroid()` by passing the `true` as a parameter. i.e. `lineString.getCentroid(true)`. 
 
 Thanks to `HimBromBeere` for his comment.